why is only one of my client side sockets receiving the emit from the server using socket.io?
So i got my server setup with express and nodejs as follows
here is a mini project which encapsulates better what i want to achieve: https://file.io/2OFIswnufLFO
I think the main problem is i dont think my socket class is setup correctly and i am unable to find any good examples that i can understand.
Can someone please help me to setup my socket class properly so that i can use the instance throughout my backend and that it can succesfully emit messages to all my clients (goint to be 3)
index.js
const express = require('express')

const { createServer } = require("http")
const { Server } = require("socket.io")
const app = express()
const socket = require('./controller/socket.js');


// Initialize socket.io
const httpServer = createServer(app)
socket.connect(httpServer);

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`)
})



And my socket class in socket.js:
let connection = null

class Socket {
    constructor() {
        this._socket = null 
    }
    connect(httpServer) {
        const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
            cors: {
                origin: "*",
                // origin: "http://localhost:8080",
                methods: ["GET", "POST"]
            }
        })

        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            this._socket = socket
            this._socket.on('statusConnetion',(data) => {
                console.log(data,'date')
            })

            this._socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                console.log(socket.id,"disconnect")
            })
            console.log(`New socket connection: ${socket.id}`)
        })
    }
    emitEvent(event, data) {
        console.log('sendFromBackendAll')
        this._socket.emit(event, data)
    }
    registerEvent(event, handler) {
        this._socket.on(event, handler)
    }
    static init(server) {
        if(!connection) {
            connection = new Socket()
            connection.connect(server)
        }
    }
    static getConnection() {
        if(!connection) {
            throw new Error("no active connection")
        }
        return connection
    }
}
module.exports = {
    connect: Socket.init,
    connection: Socket.getConnection
}




backend.js file handling client request

 

const socket = require(“../controller/socket.js”)

const update_location = (req,res) => {
const connection = socket.connection()

//do update stuff

// successfully complete update

// after successful update query i want to emit so other clients can also update. The below emitEvent works but only from one client 

if(connection)connection.emitEvent(“reloadPage”)

// return res.status(200)

}

   




FRONT_END:
socket.js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";


const URL = "http://localhost:3012";
const socket = io(URL, { autoConnect: true });



and in my vue component i have my listening events:
async created() {

    socket.on("backEmit", () => {
      console.log('hi)
    });

i got two vue clients running. When i start my server both frontend client sockets connects and console prints
New socket connection: WpZ_5__1Kq5x_BHZAAAB
New socket connection: s30YCZ7u1meF_2U4AAAD
When a request is submitted from one client a emit event is triggered to inform the other client to update.
The problem is only one clients listening is working or it is emitting to only one client because,
lets say client 1 and client 2.
When i send request from client 1, the back-end emit is triggered and client 2 hears emit and updates. Now i request from client 2 and back-end emit is triggered but then client 1 does not pick up emit event and does not update.
So only one client hears the event emitted
If anybody can help it would be great
the working client can be #2 sometimes and not #1 depending on who connected first

When a request is submitted from one client  what is meant by this? Is this code missing? Also _socket will always have the value of the latest socket that connects. Because that is what you are doing on the connection event handler

Also helpful would be to add the calls made to emitEvent. If possible try to add comments to the code too. That will help

@TusharShahi i mean by request a call made by the frontend to initiate some sort of query to the db. I added a snippet of code which illustrates how i implement the socket instance

Your socket connection code is totally wrong and buggy. please ensure you follow correct guild line and fix it

@DaksheshBaldaniya thanx, which socket connection code? the socket class in the backend?

@Llewellyn yes, socket class which you have created in your backend.

@DaksheshBaldaniya can you please help me fix my socket class so that it will be able to communicate with 3 clients. I did create a mini vue project which you can run: https://file.io/2OFIswnufLFO

This should be your socket class. please modify it according your need and must read comments for better understanding of logic.
let connection = null;

/** Manage IO and export to use it everywhere in out backend */
let io = null;

/** Manage all user's socket
 * We need to emit event for our HTTP request that's why we need to manage all connected user's socket. so we can find user's socket by user id and emit event to that user.
 */
let connectedUsers = {}; 

class Socket {
    constructor() {
    }
    connect(httpServer) {
        io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
            cors: {
                origin: "*",
                // origin: "http://localhost:8080",
                methods: ["GET", "POST"]
            }
        })

        io.use((socket, next) => {
            /** Verify user token and authorize connected client and assign user object with socket */
            socket.user = {
                id: 1,
                name: "John Doe"
            }
            next();
        })

        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            connectedUsers[socket.user.id] = socket;
            socket.on('statusConnetion',(data) => {
                console.log(data,'date')
            })

            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                console.log(socket.id,"disconnect")
            })
            console.log(`New socket connection: ${socket.id}`)
        })
    }
    /** Emit event to specific user */
    emitEvent(userId, event, data) {
        connectedUsers[userId].emit(event, data)
    }
    /** Emit event to all connected user */
    emitEventToAllClient(event, data) {
        io.emit(event, data)
    }

    static init(server) {
        if(!connection) {
            connection = new Socket()
            connection.connect(server)
        }
    }
    static getConnection() {
        if(!connection) {
            throw new Error("no active connection")
        }
        return connection
    }
}
module.exports = {
    connect: Socket.init,
    connection: Socket.getConnection
}

You can also save user's socketId in redis or global variable instead of connectedUsers to manage connected socket clients.
Please up vote and approve my answer if it help
